# Is it possible to alter the bounds of a WPF element?

Tags: wpf, bounding-box, bounds

I am creating a `Path` dynamically and I've noticed that the bounding `Rect` of the shape is far larger than the path itself, like in the picture bellow.

[image]

Is it possible to **alter those bounds?** Unfortunatelly the `PathGeometry.Bounds` property is read-only.

ps: If it helps, I am interested in narrowing the bounds so I can set `RenderTransformOrigin` of the path to `new Point(0.5,0.5)` to Rotate (`RotateTransform`) that path around itself.

### Creation of PathFigure

I am defining 4 points and then I create three `LineSegment`s and the `ArcSegment`. I've created a `Circle` struct to use as a guide to calculate those points.

```
private PathFigure CreateFigure()
        {
            var lineAB = new LineSegment(pointB, true);
            var arcBC = new ArcSegment(pointC, new Size(_outerCircle.Radius, _outerCircle.Radius), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true);
            var lineCD = new LineSegment(pointD, true);

            return new PathFigure(pointA, new List<PathSegment> { lineAB, arcBC, lineCD }, true);
        }
```

Comment: How do you create that Path? The Bounds don't make sense unless you did something weird. Besides that, you just want to rotate that circle segment?

Comment: But this path is what I want. The bounds are the problem. To be honest `PathGeometry.Transform` looks interesting. I thought transform could be set only for `Visuals`.

Comment: You should make sure that you use a coordinates that are centered at (0,0), as in my answer, where the circle center is at (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's impossible to alter the bounds after they're defined, adding the `Path` as a child to a `Grid` or a `Border` and setting `Path.Stretch="Fill"` would force the bounds to be filled by the path during the layout pass.